# How to declare an array using all elements of another array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Assume I have a "constant" like:

```
ITEMS = [ "item1", "item2" ]
```

Now I would like to create an array that contains all entries of `ITEMS`, plus some more.

Obviously, this is wrong:

```
more_things = [ "all", ITEMS ]
```

as it would put the whole array into the new array. But I want the new array to contain `[ "all", "item1", "item2" ]` in the end.

Sure, I could somehow iterate the first array, but I am wondering if there is a more idiomatic one liner way to do this. Ideally, it should work for python2 and python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate them with `+`:

```
more_things = ["all"] + ITEMS
```

Comment: @GhostCat yep, works for both major versions of Python; I didn't downvote, but IMO people are more likely to downvote this for the abundance of duplicates than its simplicity.

Comment: @GhostCat StackOverflow works in mysterious ways, but if I had to guess it could be fear of retribution

Comment: Ah, well. I really dont mind simple (correct) close as dup votes. If there would have been one early on,I just delete the question and move on. But comment-less downvotes, that sucks. And I think hope assume that I dont have a reputation of going revenging things ...

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Python 3.5+, the closest to your request is to use [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
>>> ITEMS = ['item1', 'item2']
>>> ['all', *ITEMS]
['all', 'item1', 'item2']
```

In earlier versions list concatenation would do the same:

```
>>> ITEMS = ['item1', 'item2']
>>> ['all'] + ITEMS
['all', 'item1', 'item2']
```

If you simply need an *iterable* (i.e. not necessarily a list), using [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) may be more efficient:

```
from itertools import chain
more_things = chain(['all'], ITEMS)  # or wrap in list() to get a list
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can do:

```
ITEMS = [ "item1", "item2" ]
more_things = [ "all", *ITEMS ]
```

This is quite flexible because it lets you combine several lists (or iterables in general) and elements in one line:

```
even_more_things = [ "all", *ITEMS, "the", *ITEMS, "items" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest one more obvious approach: [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures).

```
ITEMS.insert(0, 'all')
ITEMS
# ['all', 'item1', 'item2']
```

It modifies `ITEMS` in-place.

---

If you don't want to modify `ITEMS`, you can create a copy... although at that point, you'd rather one of the simpler options like iterable unpacking (`*`)...

```
ITEMS2 = ITEMS.copy()
ITEMS2.insert(0, 'all')

ITEMS2
# ['all', 'item1', 'item2']
```

Comment: ITEMS is supposed to be a "constant". more_things on the other hand is supposed to go into a choices array for argparse. So my question is really about creating a new array, without changing the first one. But sure, it is worth noting that changing is possible, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain

more_things = list(chain(more_things, ITEMS))
```

it is useful when you want to add more than two lists together.